# Use Scala type system to prevent leakage of managed resource from bracket type combinator

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Consider the following combinator for functors wrapping effectful computations:

```
def bracket[F[_]: Effect, A, R](alloc: F[R])(use: R => F[A], release: R => F[Unit]): F[A]
```

`Effect` can be assumed to be a suitable typeclass for an effectful functor. The exact implementation of `Effect` is irrelevant, but for a concrete example consider `cats.effect.IO` from https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect

This combinator intends to safely sequence evaluation of `use` with allocation and release of an external resource `R` which may incur substantial creation, destruction, or maintenance costs. `use` is not evaluated if `alloc` expresses runtime failure. `release` is evaluated regardless of any runtime failures expressed in `use`. Lingering instances of `R` remaining addressable after evaluation of `release` are assumed to be completely unusable and represent deallocated resources.

As written here the `bracket` combinator is unsafe. Consider:

```
/** Holds a real world mutable and/or expensive resource. */
type OpenThing

def allocExpensive[F[_]: Effect]: F[OpenThing] = ???
def releaseRuntime(ot: OpenThing): F[Unit] = ???

def leaks[F[_]: Effect] =
    bracket[F, R, R](allocExpensive[F])
                    ((r: R) => Effect[F].pure(r), 
                     (r: R) => releaseRuntime(r))

def breaks[F[_]: Effect]: F[Doom] =
    for {
        deadRef <- leaks[F]
    } yield deadRef.totallyIllegal
```

This example encodes a very direct unsafe use, but more subtle versions are clearly possible wherein `A =:= R` is not true, but `A` embeds, closes over, or otherwise maintains a link to handles to dead resources found within `R`.

My question:

Is there a way to change either the signature of `bracket` to prevent leaking instances of `R`?

Alternately if one employs `bracket` similar to:

```
def withOpenThing[F[_], A](job: OpenThing => F[A]): F[A] =
    bracket[F, A, OpenThing](allocExpensive[F])(job, releaseRuntime)
```

is there a way of constructing OpenThing that could prevent it from being referenced within `A`?

The whole endeavor seems like a long shot to me, but there are more things in the Scala type system than are dreamt of in my feeble imagination.